# Running command on freeSSHD server with WinSCP fails with "Your shell is probably incompatible with the application (BASH is recommended)"

Tags: bash, powershell, ssh, winscp, winscp-net

I am using below script to Verify checksum of a remote file against a local file. The server I installed on my machine is freeSSHd.

When I tried to execute the below script using PowerShell ISE I get an error message saying:

> Your shell is probably incompatible with the application (BASH is recommended)

[image: Screenshot of error]

I've granted shell access in the FreeSSHd Server User properties:
[image: FreeSSHd settings]

Script:

```
param (
    # Use Generate URL function to obtain a value for -sessionUrl parameter.
    $sessionUrl = "sftp://user:mypassword;fingerprint=ssh-rsa-xx-xx-xx@example.com/",
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
    $localPath,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
    $remotePath,
    [Switch]
    $pause = $False
)

try
{
    Write-Host $localPath -foregroundcolor Gray


# Calculate local file checksum
$localChecksum = ((CertUtil -hashfile $localPath SHA1)[1] -replace " ","")

# Write-Host "Local Checksum:"
Write-Host $localChecksum

# Load WinSCP .NET assembly
#Add-Type -Path (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "WinSCPnet.dll")
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("\\c:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll") | Out-Null

# Setup session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions
$sessionOptions.ParseUrl($sessionUrl)

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

try
{
    # Connect
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)

    Write-Host $remotePath -foregroundcolor Gray

    # Calculate remote file checksum
    $sha1Command = "bash sha1sum -b $remotePath | awk '{print `$1}'"

    $result = $session.ExecuteCommand($sha1Command)
    $result.Check()
    $remoteChecksum = $result.Output;
    #$remoteChecksum =
        [System.BitConverter]::ToString($session.CalculateFileChecksum("sha-1", $remotePath))

    # Write-Host "Remote Checksum:"
    Write-Host $remoteChecksum
}
finally
{
    # Disconnect, clean up
    $session.Dispose()
}

# Compare cheksums
if ($localChecksum -eq $remoteChecksum)
{
    Write-Host
    Write-Host "Match" -foregroundcolor "green"
    $result = 0
}
else
{
    Write-Host
    Write-Host "Does NOT match" -foregroundcolor "red"
    $result = 1
}
}
catch [Exception]
{
Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
$result = 1
}

# Pause if -pause switch was used
if ($pause)
{
    Write-Host "Press any key to exit..."
    [System.Console]::ReadKey() | Out-Null
}

exit $result
```

Comment: Looks to be a comparability issue with freeSSHd as this message isn't powershell related.

Comment: Voting to close. Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: what you mean by comparability issue?..Did you mean compatibility issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeSSHd server does not support any "bash". Its "shell" is Windows `cmd.exe`.

Your code cannot work. Windows `cmd.exe` is not compatible with WinSCP.

*Moreover FreeSSHd is pretty buggy, do not use it.*

---

You should use another Windows SSH server.

- You can use [Windows build of OpenSSH](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server). It would allow you to execute a PowerShell script on the server to calculate the checksum.

  If you install [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about), you may even get the `sha1sum` (but I'm not sure).
- You can use [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), if you need to simulate *nix environment on Windows.
- You can use [Bitvise SSH Server](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server) for personal use for free. Its SFTP server supports checksum calculation on its own, so you would be able to use WinSCP [`Session.CalculateFileChecksum` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_calculatefilechecksum) directly.

There are lot of other options.